# Strong Correlation(89%) but negetive coefficient with value (-0.00)

Tags: python, linear-regression, correlation, prediction, coefficients

My dataframe has 8 Columns ( *target_var='I62'* ). when I am running my python pandas *corr()* it give me a very good correlation between my target_var and *IOF2 and H6*.

```
# This data is till 2019-Dec
    df3Train = pd.read_csv('I62Trainv7.csv', parse_dates=['Value_Date'],index_col=['Value_Date'])
    df3Train.corr()
```

Please see below image
[Correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7yeD.png)

Using 'I62'(y), and "[IOF2,H6]" (x), I created the LinearRegression model from sklearn. When I am looking for the **coefficient** of the model it shows me negative (-0.004) coefficient for H6:

```
# Model building with I62 and IOF2 and H6
    y = df3TrainClean["I62"]
# Independent Vars
    x = df3TrainClean[['IOF2', 'H6']]
# Training on 80% Testing 20%
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

    lrModel = LinearRegression()
    lrModel.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print(lrModel.score(x_test, y_test))
    print(lrModel.score(x_train, y_train))

# Lets train the model
    lrModel.fit(x,y)    
    yPred = lrModel.predict(x_test)

# Coefficients
    coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(lrModel.coef_, x.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
    coeff_df
```

[Coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtG7U.png)

I am bit lost, when there is a good correlation, how come the coefficient is too low (and negetive) !!!
Can anyone please explain and the impact of this negetive coefficient on the predictions.

Thanks

Comment: Paste code and result instead of images please

Answer (score 0):

Negative correlation means that when one value increases, the other decreases. Correlation can take a value of -1, which means that two values always move in opposite directions. A correlation of 0 means that the movement of one does not imply the movement of another -- i.e. they are not correlated at all.